# With jQuery, add higher z-index object to an unknown location in the DOM?

Tags: jquery, dom, z-index

I know you can find() things and replace() things, but what I have to do is find something in a foreign site (not really foreign, it is national site of which we are a local site...but diff codebase, ok?). It is a national form that I am framing in my local page, and I want to replace the national "Cancel" link with my own. I can do that on the first screen because I know where it is, but the form screens are variable sizes, and that Cancel link could be anywhere. (see image for the problem). So I am trying to say: "Find this class wherever it is in the DOM, and then somehow create a higher layer and plaster my object on top of it whereever it is". Is this even possible?[image: My Cancel and theirs]

Comment: I'm a little confused what the DOM actually is in this case...it is two DOMs, and it looks intermingled in my console. But I can't just steal and override that foreign class...can I?

Comment: Any idea to frame the question properly so that we can understand..!!

Comment: sorry if you find it difficult to understand...I stated the case as specifically as I can.

Answer (score 0):

This got mooted by events, but I think I would still have to find and replace the object...you either have the DOM node available or you don't. At the very least, if I could not directly manipulate it,  I would have to find the position of the object and add my new object in the same coordinates.